# submit form at dropdown change event in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

here is my code

```
 <div id="pro_pag2">
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Product", "Main", new { customerId = mdlLoginData.CustomerID,   GroupID = ViewBag.GroupID, page = 1 }, FormMethod.Post, new { }))
                    {
                        @Html.DropDownList("PageSize", new SelectList(new   Dictionary<string, string> {{ "18", "18" }, { "12", "12" },{ "6", "6" }  }, "Key", "Value"), new { @class = "pro_pag_tf1" })
                    }
</div>
```

my question is that how do I submit form at selection change of the dropdown

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use jQuery. Give the drop down list an id, like so.

```
 <div id="pro_pag2">
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Product", "Main", new { customerId = mdlLoginData.CustomerID,   GroupID = ViewBag.GroupID, page = 1 }, FormMethod.Post, new { }))
      {
           @Html.DropDownList("PageSize", 
                new SelectList(new Dictionary<string, string> {...}, "Key", "Value"), 
                new { @class = "pro_pag_tf1", id = "pagesizelist" })
      }
 </div>
```

Then use jQuery to submit its parent form

```
$('#pagesizelist').on('change', function(event){
    var form = $(event.target).parents('form');

    form.submit();
});
```

Comment: You can also just use `$(this)` to refer to the target element instead of `$(event.target)` and that way you can also remove the `event` parameter from the handler; a little cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: @asymptoticFault That is true, it is a little bit simpler that way (though maybe not as easy to read, if you do not understand that $(this) refers to the event scope.